# extract/split from string in bash

Tags: regex, bash, split

I have a set of commands in a bash script, eg running a query in impala.

```
#! /bin/sh
RESULT=`impala-shell -q "select count(*) from testable"`
```

The result of the shell script is.

```
Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
Connected to mycomp.cool-cluster.com:21000
Server version: impalad version 2.0.0-cdh5 RELEASE (build 12323323)
Query: select count(*) from enriched_call
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.62s
+----------+ | count(*) | +----------+ | 234343 | +----------+
```

I would want to get only the value from this output ie, 234343 and try to assert the count in a script using Regex, split etc.

If I try to eliminate non numeric vaules, numbers from the version also come in.  I want to split by say '|' and get the value `234343`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RESULT=$( impala-shell -q "..." | tail -n 1 | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+' )
```

or

```
RESULT=$( impala-shell -q "..." | sed -n '$s/[^[:digit:]]//gp' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
RESULT=$(
    impala-shell -q "select count(*) from testable" |
        awk -F'|' 'END{print $4}'
)
```